# cannot use vue-router routes in axios file

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-router

I need to redirect to login page if backend throws 401-Unauthorised error. But when I try to use router.push('/login) it throws router is not defined error in axios interceptor.
Here is my axios.js file.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from "axios"
import router from '../router'

_axios.interceptors.response.use(
 function(response) {
  return response
 },
 function(error) {
  if(error.response.status == 401){
   router.push('/login')
  }
  return Promise.reject(error)
 }
)
```

This is router.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import store from '../store'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
{
 path: '/login',
 name: 'Login',
 meta: {
  layout: 'login',
  requireAuth: false,
  icon: null
 },
 component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "login" */ 
 '../components/common/auth/login-form'),
}]

const router = new VueRouter({
 mode: 'history',
 base: process.env.BASE_URL,
 routes
})
export default router
```

And defining {router} in axios gives this error in terminal npm run serve:
[image]

If I try with import router from '../router' in axios file I got this error:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you import the router in the file that you have the interceptor in ?

Comment: Yes I have. updated the axios code here.

Comment: The error in your console screenshot shows that the problem is `axios.post()`, nothing to do with `router`. Seems you haven't imported axios correctly in your store file

Answer (score 0):

use default export `import router from '../router'` instead of named import like you have in answer, `cause you have default export only in file where you define router

Comment: I tried it but that's not working as well. Giving the error in console regarding some state method in the index.js file. Updated the question and put a screenshot of the error there @Guzaro

Comment: @DarshanSoni your question still shows `import { router }`

Comment: @Phil I meant I have added the screenshot of the errors. But now updated the import statement as welll